# ValueConverter Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

#### What I am trying to achieve

I would like to create a `ValueConverter` for my application so that I can encrypt string values in my database. I know [this exists](https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption), I would prefer to do it myself.

#### The issue I am running into

I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error when I try to call my context. I have tried removing properties, rewriting constructors, changed up static methods, with no success.

#### Code

###### Value Converter

```
public class AesGcmConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public AesGcmConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = default) : base(EncryptExpr, DecryptExpr, mappingHints)
    {
            
    }
        
    static Expression<Func<string, string>> DecryptExpr = x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray());
    static Expression<Func<string, string>> EncryptExpr = x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

###### EF

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            var attributes = property.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Any())
            {
                property.SetValueConverter(new AesGcmConverter());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On which line do you catch exception?
hint : *perhaps you have `null string` value in database, then calling `x.Reverse()` would throw `NullReferenceObject` exception when `x is null`*